# Correctly output grouped data from multiple tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, relationship

there is a problem with the output of all data in one collection.
There are 3 tables Example: categories, products_group, products.
I tried to link tables via lanks but since the product table can be without a group, this is not the case.

### Migrations

```
categories
-id
-title
...
```

```
products_group
-id
-title
...
```

```
products
-id
-title
-category_id
-product_group_id
...
```

### Models

```
category
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

```
products_group
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            Product::class
        )->whereNull('product_group_id');
    }
```

Products can be in a group without it.
How do I make a request to generate a response in this format:

```
$result = [
            [
                'category_id' => 1,
                'title' => 'Category 1',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 1,
                        'title' => 'Product group 1',
                        'products' => [
                            [
                                'title' => 'product 1',
                                'product_group_id' => 1,
                                '...'
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'product 2',
                                'product_group_id' => 1,
                                '...'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 2,
                        'title' => 'Product group 2',
                        'products' => [
                            [
                                'title' => 'product 1',
                                'product_group_id' => 1,
                                '...'
                            ],
                            [
                                'title' => 'product 2',
                                'product_group_id' => 1,
                                '...'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 2,
                'title' => 'Category 2',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'title' => 'product 3',
                        'product_group_id' => null,
                        '...'
                    ],
                    [
                        'title' => 'product 4',
                        'product_group_id' => null,
                        '...'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [...]
        ];
```

Not how it doesn't work out to form all this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Products can be in a group without it"? And `return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->whereNull('product_group_id');` doesn't make sense to me. For the output you desire there needs to be a relation between Category and ProductGroup

Comment: I can't imagine how to make a connection between Gategory and ProductGroup.
If you link these tables with an intermediate table, then you will have to make another request to get products without ProductGroup. But is it possible to link Gategory and ProductGroup with the Product table?

Comment: Linking Category and ProductGroup with intermediate pivot table - the query can then be of form `Category::with(['product_groups.products', 'products'])->get()` to get all products which are associated with any ProductGroup as well as Products which are not associated with any ProductGroup in a single query

Comment: As I understand the relationship between Category and ProductGroup do like this
`public function product_groups()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            ProductGroup::class,
            Product::class,
            'category_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'product_group_id' // Local key on users table...
        )->groupBy('product_group_id');
    }`

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @Donkarnash Then it turns out in the table where the group of products and just products. I think this is a redundant array.

Comment: You don't need hasManyThrough, you can just have a pivot table with category_id and product_group_id with belongsToMany relation on both sides on Category model for product_groups and on ProductGroup model for categories.

Comment: @Donkarnash Thank you for your help, we will sort it out! What about products that is duplicated in categories where products are located in groups?

Comment: You can have constraint in the with() to only eager load the products where the product_group_id is null for the products relation on categories

Comment: @Donkarnash

This is clear I mean that in those categories where products are grouped they are displayed normally but also the same products are displayed in the products array the same category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Donkarnash This is clear I mean that in those categories where products are grouped they are displayed normally but also the same products are displayed in the products array the same category

You can have a constraint while eager loading relationships

```php
$categories = Category::with([
    'product_groups.products',
    'products' => function($query){
        $query->whereNull('product_group_id');
    }
)->get();
```

This will eager load all ProductGroup records with related Product records within the ProductGroup and also the Product records associated with the Category which are not associated with any ProductGroup.

Above query is assuming that you have a pivot table `category_product_group` and belongsToMany relationship on both sides Category and ProductGroup

```
//category_product_group
 - category_id
 - product_group_id
//with composite primary key of category_id & product_group_id
```

Relationship

```php
//Category.php
public function product_groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductGroup::class);
}

//ProductGroup.php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I also did only the conditions in the wrong place made.

Comment: @ValenokPC If the answer has helped solve the issue in question pls remember to mark it as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors

Comment: Tell me how to add data to the linking table

Comment: You can use `attach`, `detach` or `sync` to associate the related records https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks! Everything went well.